# Gnome-terminal in Kubuntu shrinks to minimum size

Tags: kubuntu, kde, gnome-terminal

When I open a gnome-terminal in Kubuntu 13.10, the window shrinks to the minimum size, about 20 columns and 1 row. This also occurs when I maximize and then restore the window, or I use the Terminal menu to adjust the columns and rows. This does not happen when I open 
konsole, lxterm, or lxterminal.

Version information

- Kubuntu v13.10 AMD 64
- Plasma Desktop using Qt: 4.8.4 / Plasma Desktop Shell 4.11.5
- GNOME Terminal version v3.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.  According to the GNOME bugtracker, there's a bug with how the gnome-terminal window handles geometry. Ref: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649680

The answer is also there, towards the bottom. I'll clarify and paraphrase it here:

1. In KDE, go to System Settings.  Return to the overview if you are not already there.
2. In the **Workspace Appearance and Behavior** section, click Window Behavior.
3. In the area to the left, click the **Window Rules** icon. Add a new rule.  The Description should be "Shrinking gnome-terminal workaround".  Click the 2nd tab, "Size & Position".  Then click the bottom checkbox option, "Obey geometry restrictions", to "Force", and then set the radio button to "No".  Once you hit OK, it won't work until you hit "Apply" on the parent window.

Now terminals won't shrink anymore.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to add step of window matching (e.g. via "Match window properties" button. Also, if you feel this answer completely answers your question, you can accept it so that others see your question as answered.

Comment: Is there a fix for when running Gnome?

Comment: No, this fix was purely for running gnome-terminal in a KDE/plasma environment.  Gnome-terminal should handle itself correctly in Gnome 2/Metacity or Gnome 3/Gnome Shell. If you are using Mate or Cinnamon or Gnome with a different window manager, you are probably better off starting a new question on Ask Ubuntu.