# Gnome-terminal in Ubuntu Unity shrinks to minimum size

Tags: upgrade, themes, update-manager, 15.04

When I open a terminal in Ubuntu 15.04, it shrinks to 1 character by 1 character. I can use the corner resizer to make the window bigger, but it immediately shrinks to 1x1. There are a few x,y combinations that allow the window to stay at the desired size, but if you're off by a pixel, the window shrinks to 1x1.

There is another question, [Gnome-terminal in Kubuntu shrinks to minimum size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423733/gnome-terminal-in-kubuntu-shrinks-to-minimum-size), that is basically the same thing, but in KDE. I tried to follow the instructions:

> In KDE, go to System Settings. Return to the overview if you are not
>   already there. In the Workspace Appearance and Behavior section, click
>   Window Behavior. In the area to the left, click the Window Rules icon.

but, there is no Workspace Appearance and Behavior section.
I couldn't find a similar setting in ccsm, gnome-tweak-tool or unity-tweak-tool.

```
% dpkg-query --show compiz
compiz  1:0.9.12.1+15.04.20150410.1-0ubuntu1
% dpkg-query --show unity
unity   7.3.2+15.04.20150420-0ubuntu1
```

The problem appears to be in the Adwaita theme. To avoid this problem, I opened the System Settings/Appearance and set the Theme to Ambiance (default).

Comment: I think a similar setting is in the normal Unity System Settings.

Comment: Well...what is it? Where is it? I looked under the Appearance icon, and didn't find anything relevant. None of the other icons appear to be relevant.

Comment: I'm trying to think of it. I can't remember.

Comment: I've this problem too, if you've found any solution, please share it here.

Comment: Same problem here, I use Terminator in the meantime.

Comment: same problem for me

Comment: In the process of filing a bug, ubuntu-bug -w reported that the package, gnome-terminal, had a dependency on a local library, /local/usr/local/lib/libexpat.so.1.6.0. I searched and found:
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 165280 Oct 21  2014 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 166000 Oct 21  2014 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 545601 Jul 12  2013 /local/usr/local/lib/libexpat.so.1.6.0
So, I deleted the local one, but the problem persists.

Comment: Could you try opening a terminal, press [alt][T], release the [Alt] and then press [1].  What does this do?

Comment: Pressing [Alt][T] does nothing. Releasing [Alt] results in the letter [t]  being repeating in the window. Pressing [1] adds a "1" to the text in the window.

Comment: Still hitting this profoundly annoying bug on my end here.  Have been trying to use some other terminal apps with some measured success, but this is a crazy issue to have this long after release for so many.

Comment: Switch themes, away from the adwaita theme. Adwaita seems to be broken. I filed a bug, https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=750156, on 5/31, but it doesn't look like anything has been done with it. It might help if you added your comment to the bug, so they could see it's affecting multiple users.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1451944) has not yet been resolved.  As you can see, this is due to an issue with using Adwaita, BUT:

### I found that switching to the [Vertex theme](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Vertex+-+Theme?content=166318) was not only an acceptable solution, but I think I prefer it to other options right now:

[image: Vertex Theme]

Instructions are here: [Github Installation Section](https://github.com/horst3180/Vertex-theme#installation), but I simply used the xUbuntu packages [here](http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3AHorst3180&package=vertex-theme) for Ubuntu 15.04; drop to shell and do:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_15.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vertex-theme.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vertex-theme
```

I then wanted to get the matching icons, and so used [this for reference](https://github.com/horst3180/Vertex-Icons#requirements):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:moka/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install moka-icon-theme
mkdir ~/.icons
cd ~/.icons
git clone https://github.com/horst3180/Vertex-Icons.git
```

Hopefully you already have Unity Tweak Tool (`sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`) installed.  Then simply go in to its Appearance section -> Theme and pick `Vertex-dark` for your Theme and then pop over to Icons and select `Vertex-icons` if you like.

FYI, Breeze icons also look nice or perhaps just Moka itself without Vertex.  If you like the icons from the screenshot above, [use Ardis](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/04/ardis-ardis-basic-ursa-ursa-basic-icons.html).

Comment: Sadly, also with the Vertex Theme this problem isn't solved. At least not with remmina and synaptic/update-manager's windows, where it shows you the progress of the installation - when you let it show the details. It always gets back to minimal size :/

EDIT: I guess that's a different error. Thanks for the Vertex theme, tho, love it.

Answer (score -1):

Open terminal (CTRL+ALT+T)

Hold ALT then + T and use some of the options to reset the size.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't see what Alt+T should do... No reaction of my gnome-terminal window on 15.04 for me. Could you please explain what should happen? Ideally with a screen shot, if possible. You can upload an image to http://imgur.com manually and paste the link here, as you don't have enough rep points yet to insert it directly.

Comment: ALT+T does nothing. If pressed after creating the window and it's shrinking, nothing changes. If pressed after the window is at its minimum size, nothing happens.